# Action of permutations over polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, permutations

Let $f,g\in K\left[ x_{1},x_{2} \right]$ eb homogeneous polynomials, and $\sigma\in S_{2}$ a permutation; denote by $\sigma\cdot f=f(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)})$; prove the following:

$$\text{if:    }f\sigma\cdot f=g\sigma\cdot g$$
then
$$f=g \text{  or  }f=\sigma\cdot g$$

I've thought about it for a bit but I've no idea on where to start

Comment: When you say $f\sigma\cdot f$, do you mean the standard polynomial product of $f$ and $\sigma \cdot f$?

Comment: What about $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2$, $g(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$, $\sigma=(12)$?

Comment: Yes I think you found a counterexample @ancientmathematician

Comment: Do you see any condition on f or g that could make the statement hold true? For example, what if neither f or g are symmetric?

Comment: Yes @Arthur, that's the standard polynomial product